# mysql sql optimization - left outer join

Tags: mysql, sql

For some reason this select message is really slow.

i've been having a difficult time testing it, it is slow once then fast, adding 'sql_no_cache' doesn't seem to change its speed much.

messages has about 1.5million rows, users about 70k.

It appears to be using the indexes, but it is still slow... :(

Any help much appreciated.

```
mysql> SELECT  count(DISTINCT `messages`.id) AS count_all FROM `messages` LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` ON `users`.id = `messages`.sender_id WHERE (`messages`.receiver_id = 20000 AND (receiver_deleted IS NULL));

mysql> explain SELECT  count(DISTINCT `messages`.id) AS count_all FROM `messages` LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` ON `users`.id = `messages`.sender_id WHERE (`messages`.receiver_id = 20000 AND (receiver_deleted IS NULL));
+----+-------------+----------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------+--------    -------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+---------------  ------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type        | possible_keys                                           | key                                                       | key_len | ref                            | rows | Extra                                                                                  |
+----+-------------+----------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | messages | index_merge | index_messages_on_receiver_id,index_messages_on_deleted |    index_messages_on_receiver_id,index_messages_on_deleted | 4,2     | NULL                           | 6708 | Using intersect(index_messages_on_receiver_id,index_messages_on_deleted); Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users    | eq_ref      | PRIMARY                                                 | PRIMARY                                                      | 4       | mytable.messages.sender_id |    1 | Using index                                                                           |
+----+-------------+----------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: Could you also post your table definitions (SHOW CREATE TABLE)? You are using indexes, but maybe there are better candidates for indexes.

Comment: It is slow once, then fast - probably because second time data is read from the buffer.